# Ionic 6 Loading Controller Present is not a Function Error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I recently updated my ionic 4 to ionic 6. And all of sudden my loading is not working anymore, the console throws a "loading.present is not a function" error. Here's my personal loading, I'm using the loading controller component.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { MessageUtil } from './message.util';

export function easyMarineLoadingCreator(loadingController: LoadingController, messageUtil: MessageUtil) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-use-before-declare
    return new EasyMarineLoading(loadingController, messageUtil);
}

@Injectable()
export class EasyMarineLoading {

    loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement = null;
    constructor(
        private loadingController: LoadingController,
        private messageUtil: MessageUtil
    ) {
    }

    async create() {
        const options: {} = {
            message: this.messageUtil.translateKey('LOADING'),
            translucent: true
        };
        this.loader = await this.loadingController.create(options);
    }

    public async present() {
        if (!this.loader) {
            await this.create();
        }
        this.loader.present();
    }

    public async dismiss() {
        if (this.loader) {
            this.loader.dismiss();
            this.loader = null;
        }
    }

    public getLoader(): HTMLIonLoadingElement {
        if (this.loader) {
            return this.loader;
        }
        this.create();
        return undefined;
    }

    public setLoader(loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }
}
```

The error happens whenever I instanciate this service and run the .present() function...
Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post complete code including where you are calling this service from.  Also...why are you exporting a function at the top if this is an injectable service? Have you checked if any of this code is even called...for example with console.log. And why do you return undefined from getLoader? That's probably your issue...no matter if created getLoaded ALWAYS returns undefined...and mostly likely why you get the "not a function" error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and tried this:

```
this.loadingController.create({
        message: 'Loading...'
    }).then((response) => {
        response.present();
    });
```

got it from here https://www.positronx.io/ionic-loading-controller-tutorial-with-ion-loading-example/